# Reload log4j appender

Tags: java, log4j

I want to reload log4j appenders (RollingFileAppender) dynamically as the user changes the configuration from user interface.

I have programatically removed the appender and created new appender with new configuration values. After this the appender broken MaxBackupIndex and MaxFileSize is not working properly. But if I change the file name (logging filename) then it works correclty.

Can some help me here to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we take the exiting appender with the filename and update the property then the changes works correctly.